# Pygame blit on top of another?

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I'm trying to create a game, with pygame, and right now I'm attempting to blit my health bar. It's apparently there, just under the background image. Is there a way to have it blit / drawn on top of the background? I've tried re-arranging the order.

```
screen.blit(healthbar, (5,5))

for health1 in range(healthvalue):
    screen.blit(health, (health1+8,8))

screen.blit(background,(0,0))
```

Suggestions or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The order is wrong, and you should update the screen after drawing everything:

```
screen.blit(backround,(0,0))

screen.blit(healthbar, (5,5))

for health1 in range(healthvalue):
    screen.blit(health, (health1+8,8))

...

pygame.display.flip()
```